# Manter um site de um tamanho padrao mobile/desktop

Tags: html, css

Estou a desenvolver um site e preciso que ele fique do mesmo padrao de css para desktop e mobile, sem se tornar responsivo. https://br.leagueoflegends.com/pt/game-info/champions/ como esse site, se voce fazer o teste no inspecionar e testar em diferente tipos de telas mobiles, as imagens so diminuem, porem, permanecem da mesma forma. Como faria isso?

Comment: https://medium.com/@fnandaleite/entendendo-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-design-responsivo-adaptativo-e-mobile-first-ea3c61fc9181

Comment: Cara basta vc ter um Grid que trabalha com % e não declarar a viewport. Dessa forma seu layout não se adapta. Parece que é assim que fizeram. Esse é o CSS com o Grid que eles usaram https://lolstatic-a.akamaihd.net/lolkit/1.1.6/lol-kit.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [meta tag viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) para ajustar as dimensões da página para a largura e altura do dispositivo, prefira usar [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) no seu css para especificar diferentes estilos para diferentes telas, [este link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries) contém mais informações sobre a utilização do @media, escolha usar [%](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) em vez de px, pois px é uma medida fixa, enquanto % é uma medida relativa ao elemento pai.